# Can't generate APK from Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

I'm trying to generate an APK. I go to `Build` -> `Generate signed APK` and after all, I get this message:

> Error:A problem was found with the configuration of task ':app:packageRelease'.
>   File 'geovanni_geopath_keystore_02' specified for property 'signingConfig.storeFile' does not exist.

Can any one help me please? Thank you

**EDIT**

This is my `build.gradle` file, I don't know what is wrong:

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.geopath"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }



    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile files('libs/mobileservices-1.1.5-javadoc.jar')
    compile files('libs/mobileservices-1.1.5-sources.jar')
    compile files('libs/mobileservices-1.1.5.jar')
}
```

Comment: Check your `build.gradle` file whether your keystore file path is specified or not

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

According to gradle documentation, you should add this in android section after buildToolsVersion:

```
signingConfigs {
    debug {
        storeFile file("debug.keystore")
    }
}

release {
    storeFile file("release.keystore")
    storePassword "paste your own password"
    keyAlias "paste your own alias"
    keyPassword "paste your own password"
}
```

And add debug.keystore and release.keystore(optionaly) in project dir.